# different between title and title_icontains in model filter django

Tags: python, django, django-models

what is diffrent between title and title_icontains in django ?

```
from .model import product
product.objects.filter(title='blah')
product.objects.filter(tite__icontains='blah')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first form `...filter(title='value')` will return all objects whose title will match exactly the value.

And the second form, correctly written as `...filter(title__icontains)` will return all objects whose title contains the value, but any upper/lower case letters will match.
The `i` here means "ignore case".

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is `title__icontains=…` so with *two* consecutive underscores (`__`). In that case you make use of the [**`__icontains`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains). As the documentation says, this is a:

> Case-insensitive containment test.

It thus looks for `Product`s where the title *contains* `blah`. For example `fooblah`, `blahfoo`, of `fooblahbar`. It does this in a case *insensitive* manner, so products with `FooBlah`, `BLAHfoo` and `FooBlAHBAR` as title will also be retained.

Answer (score 0):

`tite__icontains` is to look fo the string, but with case-insensitive.